# What is the difference between <selector> and <shape> in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

What is the difference between `<selector>` and `<shape>` in android? When to use `<selector>`, and `<shape>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between `<selector>` and `<shape>` in android?

Other than being XML used in layout resources, they are unrelated.

> When to use `<selector>`, and `<shape>`?

`<shape>` is a way to define [a `ShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable) in a drawable resource, for representing rectangles and ovals with various borders and fills.

`<selector>` is a way to define [a `StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) in a drawable resource, for indicating other drawables to use based on the state of the widget that is applying this `StateListDrawable`.

So, in the context of a button, the `<selector>` would say what to use for the normal background, the pressed background, the disabled background, and so on. `<shape>` would be used to provide the actual background for one of those states.

You can read more about the different drawable resource types in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource).

Comment: Ohk, so you mean that the `<selector>` is used to design the whole state of button for example button is pressed, released and so on?

Comment: @Sunny: Yes. `<selector>` itself does have any artwork. You can think of `<selector>` as being a big `if`/`else if`/`else` sort of conditional structure, written in XML, to point to another drawable to use for a given state.

Comment: Can you tell one more thing, when we go for `<selector>` why we wrap the `<shape>` inside the `<item>`, why we cannot wrap the `<shape>` directly inside the `<selector>`?

Comment: @Sunny: Attributes saying "use this drawable for this combination of states" goes in the `<item>`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList).

Comment: When i tried `<item android:color="#C91F1F">` and run the app, the background of the shape is gone, why?

Comment: @Sunny: Well, among other things, `android:color` is not a valid attribute for an `<item>` element. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList).

Answer (score 1):

`<selector>` element describes `ColorStateList` in XML file, `ColorStateList` is an object that can apply as a color, but will change colors, depending on the state of the View.

Available states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="hex_color"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

`<shape>` defines a geometric shape, including colors and gradients for a `Drawable`.

Comment: What is the use case of `<item>` here? Why we cannot directly use `<shape>` inside right after `<selector>`?

Comment: When i tried `<item android:color="#C91F1F">` and run the app, the background of the shape is gone, why?

Comment: Each color is defined in an <item> element inside a single <selector> element, i am not remember but i guess you can use shape inside item element

Comment: `color` should not be used in the `<item>` element.